# Can’t Access Custom Attributes

Tags: magento

I’ve been looking all over for an answer to this. I’ve been using Magento for about a week now and Im fixing a bunch of templates that we messed up. Anyway I’m at a spot now that should probably be easy but its not working. I need to access and custom attribute… this code works.

standard attribute

```
$_product->getName()
```

but this code wont.. custom attribute of “designer”

```
$_product->getDesigner()
```

the original code from the developer had this.. however this code didn’t work either lol

```
$_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDesigner(), 'designer');
```

any help would be great thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you get $_product? Maybe u need to make a load.

$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());

Magento doesn't load all attributes of an model until you make an load.

Try to log all data in product by doing Mage::log($_product->getData()).

Comment: just tried $_product2 = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId()); $designer = $_product2->getDesigner(); and still nothing... also checked logs for both $_product & $_product2 and didn't see anything for my custom attribute of designer

Comment: here is how the developer is getting product btw ... <?php $_products = $this->getProductCollection(); ?> and then he is doing a foreach loop foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product)

Comment: OMG... ok using your solution fixed the broken code however the items i was checking didn't have designer set... i thought they all had that field set sorry... LOL could have had this solved hours ago if i would have thought to check that out

Comment: In product listing (grid), in the foreach product loop, some attributes wouldn't appear (and some would). For some reason, re-loading $_product within the loop solved it. Good to know...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `$_product` is an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`, or set it to one with `$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId())`

In addition to the "magic" getter of `$_product->getDesigner()` you could use `getData()` instead:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_product->getId());
$_designer = $_product->getData('designer');
```